# How is 1 circular mil ohm/foot = 1.66242611301 x 10-7 ohm centimeter dervied?

Tags: resistance

All,

Where does the constant: 1.66242611301 x 10-7 ohm centimeter come from?

How is it derived?

Also, why is the following true:

1 circular mil ohm/foot = 1.66242611301 x 10-7 ohm centimeter

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Unit conversion: A "circular mil" is the area of a circle with a diameter of 0.001 inch (0.0254mm). That's about 5.07 * 10^-4 mm^2, or 5.07 * 10^-6 cm^2.

A foot is 30.48 cm.

1 circular mil / 1 foot = 5.07 * 10^-6 cm^2 / 30.48 cm = 1.66 * 10^-7 cm.

"ohm" is just along for the ride.